# HTML Form - How to keep File on page reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, local-storage

I have a Form in React + Bootstrap. When reloading the page, the written text in the Email input is still there. How can I also make it so the selected file stays too?

```js
import React from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";

export default () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState(localStorage.getItem("email") || "");
  // Gives "Uncaught DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"
  const [filename, setFilename] = React.useState(localStorage.getItem("file") || "");
  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Control
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setEmail(e.target.value);
          localStorage.setItem("email", e.target.value);
        }}
        type="email"
      />
      <Form.Control
        value={filename}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFilename(e.target.value);
          localStorage.setItem("file", e.target.value);
        }}
        type="file"
      />
    </Form>
  );
};
```